# Problems using third-party library in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I am using a [library to animate `ListView`](http://nhaarman.github.io/ListViewAnimations). As is the  procedure, I added the `.jar` file to the lib directory. What this library also needs is another library to work named [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/). I downloaded that `.zip` file, too.

The 9OldAndroids library is a project folder. So, I imported that in Eclipse, added that to my build path. Eclipse shows the packages from 9OldAndroids:
[image]

However, I get an exception when running the app on my phone:

```
08-08 19:36:13.050: E/dalvikvm(27827): Could not find class 'com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator[]', referenced from method com.haarman.listviewanimations.swinginadapters.prepared.AlphaInAnimationAdapter.‌​getAnimators
```

**How do I solve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NineOldAndroids is an Android library project. You need to [attach that Android library project to your main app's project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject). Whatever you did when you "added that to [your] build path" is probably not the right answer.

Comment: I did `Project` -> `Properties` -> `Java Build Path` -> `Add Class Folder` and then added NineOldAndroids .

Comment: @LittleChild: That is not the correct procedure. Please undo that, the follow the instructions that I linked to in my answer.